# G Suite Admin portal

Tags: g-suite-administrator

I work at a district school and we have "google admin" for our students. Do you require to be certified when logging in as Super Admin?

Comment: What do you mean by certified? What makes you think that it might be required to be certified? Have you tried to log in?